# How to Make Adobe Air Extension for iOS native app

Tags: ios, air

I searched over Internet but didn't find any answer.

Question 1# is it possible to use Adobe air application in a native iOS app.??

Let me explain I am going to develop an iOS application in which I have to play flv files. I created a application in adobe air which plays flv files in iOS but I want to play flv within my native app without leaving that native app.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to inform you that if you play adobe AIR FLV file in IOS, it will not play, because IOS not supports FLV, i'm not sure about that if you put FLV in IOS native app and play it, but standalone it will not play, so first test it without native then try to implement it in native.

Comment: I have created a iOS in Adobe Air (Using Action Script) which is playing FLV in iOS. Now I want to USE that Adobe Air App within my iOS Native App (Developing in Objective C).